# Asymptotic bounds of a simple "Delay Differential Equation"

Tags: delay-differential-equations

Define the function $x(t)$ for $t\ge0$:
$$
x(0)=1\\
x'(t)=-x(t/2)
$$
I could do a power series from $t=0$ like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717438) (thanks to @JeanMarie for pointing this old question out),
but I ultimately want asymptotic bounds on the excursions as $t\to\infty$, so I don't think the power series helps.  Is there any other research on this function?  How quickly do these excursions grow with $t$?

[image: first cycles]
[image: t<100]
[image: t<1000]

Comment: See as well the excellent answer by Robert Israel [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1800161)

Comment: It is **not** a delay differential equation : it should have a term $f(t-a)$ for that...

Comment: @JeanMarie Only [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3717438) is relevant, but the power series answer (modified for the important -1 in my equation) does not help me find the asymptotic bounds I want.

Comment: Another track: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3784061

Comment: If you take the Laplace Transform with ${\frak L}(f)=F$, $F$ must verify the functional equation $sF(s)+1=-2F(2s)$. Is there a solution ?